# Magento 2.1.8 Deploy static content error

Tags: magento-2.1, adminhtml, css, static-content-deploy

I get this error in my console when trying to deploy static files:

```
Compilation from source:
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.less
Unable to get content for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Checkout/css/source/module/_checkout.less'
```

I ran: `rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/` but still experiencing this issue.

The Magento admin has no style.

How can I debug that? Anyone can help?

---

**Update:**

Permissions of `pub/` and `var/` directories:

```
drwxrwxrwx  8 www-data www-data   4096 Jan  8 12:55 pub
drwxrwxrwx 15 www-data www-data   4096 Jan  8 13:20 var
```

Comment: Try to run compile command for that and then run deploy command.

Comment: I did try it and still same thing :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to run following command from CLI.

```
chmod -R 777 pub/ var/
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: That didn't work. Still the same. Also,  `chmod -R 777` commandy sets the permissions to files and directories or just directories or just files?

Comment: It set permission to both, files & Directories. Have you run the deploy command for locale which you are used currently.

Comment: I just ran the plain command. `php-7.0 bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, by default it deploys the `en_US`. The actual error says it can't find the file from `en_US`. This is a bit strange, it uses the files from `en_GB` for frontend and `en_US` for the backend...